# saql create bar segments

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I would like to create stacked bar based on something a saql query like this:

```
q = load "datasetname";
q = filter q by 'field1' == "false" and 'field2'=="homescreen";
q = filter q by date('eventon_Year', 'eventon_Month', 'eventon_Day') in ["7 days ago".."current day"];
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate 
(sum('count_eventcount_0to1000') +
sum('count_eventcount_1000to2000') + 
sum('count_eventcount_2000to3000'))
as '0 to 3 seconds',
(sum('count_eventcount_3000to4000') +
sum('count_eventcount_4000to5000'))
as '3 to 5 seconds',
(sum('count_eventcount_5000to6000') +
sum('count_eventcount_6000to7000') + 
sum('count_eventcount_7000to8000'))
as '5 to 8 seconds',
(sum('count_eventcount_8000to9000') +
sum('count_eventcount_9000to10000'))
as '8 to 10 seconds'
q = foreach q generate '0 to 3 seconds', '3 to 5 seconds', '5 to 8 seconds', '8 to 10 seconds';
q = limit q 2000;
```

but this gives me only a row of data and I cannot make the measures I created into "bar segments".  Is there a way in which I can create different bar segments based on calculations like this above so that the stacked bar works correctly (segments are of proportional length) to values?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!  Please try to format your question so that it's easier to read (use code formatting) and you also can just post a relevant sample of code rather than a big code-dump

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by querying this way.

```
    q = load "datasetname";
q = filter q by 'field1' == "false" and 'field2'=="homescreen";
q = filter q by date('eventon_Year', 'eventon_Month', 'eventon_Day') in ["7 days ago".."current day"];
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate 
q1 = foreach q generate "0 to 3s" as '# of events',
(sum('count_mobileEPT_0to1000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_1000to2000') + 
sum('count_mobileEPT_2000to3000'))
as 'count';
q2 = foreach q generate "3s to 5s" as '# of events',
(sum('count_mobileEPT_3000to4000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_4000to5000'))
as 'count';
q3 = foreach q generate "5s to 8s" as '# of events',
(sum('count_mobileEPT_5000to6000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_6000to7000') + 
sum('count_mobileEPT_7000to8000'))
as 'count';
q4 = foreach q generate "8s to 10s" as '# of events',
(sum('count_mobileEPT_8000to9000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_9000to10000'))
as 'count';
q5 = foreach q generate "10s +" as '# of events',
(sum('count_mobileEPT_10000to11000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_11000to12000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_12000to13000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_13000to14000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_14000to15000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_15000to16000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_16000to17000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_17000to18000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_18000to19000') +
sum('count_mobileEPT_19000to20000') + 
sum('count_mobileEPT_20000to'))
as 'count';
r = union q1,q2,q3,q4,q5;
q = foreach r generate '# of events', 'count';
```